# What was the name of Tzipora's mother?

Tags: history, names, women, moshe-rabbeinu

What was the name of Tzipora's mother (Moses's mother-in-law)?

There are a lot of wives mentioned in the Torah, but the names of some aren't mentioned even though they are important. So I was curious about this particular one.

Comment: I don't think this is knon

Answer (score 8):

The name of אשת יתרו is "unknown". See [here](http://www.doresh-tzion.co.il/QAShowAnswer.aspx?qaid=47417).

Comment: I guess my Hebrew might be a bit poor, but is he saying that it is not known, or that he doesn't know?

Comment: It means unknown

Comment: Meaning the info is not available

Comment: In fairness, the rav is not being asked the name of Yitro's wife, but whether or not there is a *source* for that name. For all I know, the person asking the question has a name in mind and wants to know if it can be substantiated. I doubt that's so, but since he only asked for a source, the rav's answer that "it is not known" is a reference to the existence of such a source and nothing else. As such, it can't be used to demonstrate that "the name of אשת יתרו is unknown", as you have said.

Comment: @ShimonbM, if, as you acknowledge, the _t'shuva_ says there's no known source for a name for _Yisro_'s wife, then there seem to be only two possibilities: that there's no known name for _Yisro_'s wife, and that her name is known sans source (i.e. _mipi hash'mua_ through a chain of tradition). The latter seems exceedingly unlikely to me in this day and age.

Comment: I agree, @msh210, I'm just being picky. And I didn't downvote, even if I don't think it's much of a source.

Answer (score 4):

According to [the Medrash Talpiyot [Bisyoh]](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=33215&pgnum=222), some say that Tzipora was a sister of Moshe's. In that case, her mother was Yocheved bas Levi.

Comment: What!? I don't understand how this is possible,am I missing something?

Comment: Moshe married his sister?

Comment: look at the source [i dont know how to make the fancy hyperlinks]

Comment: don't forget that at matan torah he devorced her

Comment: rabbi, welcome to Mi Yodeya, and thanks for the fascinating answer! I hope you stick around and enjoy the site. For help with formatting answers (and questions), you can see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/editing-help; more generally, for site help, see http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help.

Comment: This is a really hard Midrash to understand, as [this sefer](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=34355&st=&pgnum=48) asks: 1) If so, she would have been three months old when she saved Moshe, and she was already talking by then! 2) Why does the Midrash say he didn't want to marry *both* of them because he didn't want to marry two sisters; just marrying Tziporah was a problem of marrying *his* sister.

Comment: It should be noted that this is a Sabbatean work.

Comment: @Michoel as I noted [this is a Sabbatian work](http://www.daat.ac.il/daat/vl/YovelMarks/YovelMarks13.pdf) the author probably thought it was funny to encourage sin by portraying the Law-giver of violating it.